# Default permissions of folders in pimcore

Tags: php, pimcore

I am always getting permission issues in pimcore so I am not sure What should be the default permissions of folders in pimcore?

Answer (score 0):

On [official documentation](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/File_Permissions.html) of Pimcore you can read:

> Pimcore requires write access to the following directories:
>   /app/config, /bin, /composer.json, /pimcore, /var, /web/pimcore and
>   /web/var.

More regarding execute permissions and ownership of files you'll find under the link I posted above.